# Draggable popup window in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a popuo window that is created using java script. JQuery cannot be used. I want to make this popup window draggable. That is to allow it to move on mousemove. Is there anyway to make this happen in javascript.

It could be helpful if there is any single function or method in javascript. It is just a normal popup window. So there are no restrictions in it but it is developed only in javascript (cannot make use of jquery). Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you not able to use JQuery in this case? http://jsfiddle.net/LQ4JT/510/

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>Hello, world!</div>
<button id="btn_popup">popup</button>
<div id="smoke"style="display:none;position:absolute;top:-30px;left:-30px;opacity:0.3;background-color:black;z-index:9998">...</div>
<div id="popup" style="display:none;background-color:green;position:absolute;top:0px;z-index:9999;box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #888888;border-radius:6px;border:1px solid #4f4f4f;">
  <div id="popup_bar" style="width:100%;background-color:#aaff66;position:relative;top:0;border-radius:6px 6px 0 0; text-align:center;height:24px;cursor:move">Title<span id="btn_close" style="float:right;cursor:pointer;padding-right:6px;">[X]</span></div>
  <p>Popup Window.<br>Press ESC to close.</p>
</div>
</body>
<script>
(function(){

var SCROLL_WIDTH = 24;

var btn_popup = document.getElementById("btn_popup");
var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
var popup_bar = document.getElementById("popup_bar");
var btn_close = document.getElementById("btn_close");
var smoke = document.getElementById("smoke");

//-- let the popup make draggable & movable.
var offset = { x: 0, y: 0 };

popup_bar.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);

function mouseUp()
 {
 window.removeEventListener('mousemove', popupMove, true);
 }

 function mouseDown(e){
  offset.x = e.clientX - popup.offsetLeft;
  offset.y = e.clientY - popup.offsetTop;
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', popupMove, true);
  }

  function popupMove(e){
   popup.style.position = 'absolute';
  var top = e.clientY - offset.y;
  var left = e.clientX - offset.x;
  popup.style.top = top + 'px';
   popup.style.left = left + 'px';
  }
   //-- / let the popup make draggable & movable.

   window.onkeydown = function(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 27){ // if ESC key pressed
    btn_close.click(e);
   }
   }

   btn_popup.onclick = function(e){
   // smoke
    spreadSmoke(true);
  // reset div position
   popup.style.top = "4px";
   popup.style.left = "4px";
    popup.style.width = window.innerWidth - SCROLL_WIDTH + "px";
   popup.style.height = window.innerHeight - SCROLL_WIDTH + "px";
   popup.style.display = "block";
   }

    btn_close.onclick = function(e){
    popup.style.display = "none";
     smoke.style.display = "none";
    }

   window.onresize = function(e){
    spreadSmoke();
    }

   function spreadSmoke(flg){
   smoke.style.width = window.outerWidth + 100 + "px";
    smoke.style.height = window.outerHeight + 100 + "px";
    if (flg != undefined && flg == true) smoke.style.display = "block";
    }

   }());
   </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Here is what you exactly want, without jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

Have a global boolean variable `dragging`. Then, to your `document.body`, append three event handlers.

- on `mousedown`, set `dragging = true`
- on `mousemove`, check if `dragging == true`. If it is, check the `x, y` of your mouse position (in the `event` object). Set your element's css:

  ```
  position: absolute
  left: x + 'px'
  top: y + 'px'
  ```
- on `mouseup`, set `dragging = false`

On `mousedown`, you'll probably also want to measure where exactly in the element you clicked, so it is that exact point in your element that follows the mouse cursor, not the element's upper left corner.

And you'll probably want to wrap the whole thing a nice class to avoid global variables and have it reusable :)

Comment: javascript does not have classes.